# What are 1Ag and 1Bu excitons?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was going through a paper in organic LED. Saw that there were 1Ag and 1Bu excitons (also 2Ag and 2Bu excitons) which I don't really understand. I am from engineering background. Can anyone help me understanding this terminology?

Comment: These are just symmetry labels for the orbitals involved in excitations. They tell you which irreducible representation (of a point group your molecule belongs to) a particular orbital corresponds. See, for instance, [this question](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16305/symmetry-labels-for-orbitals).

Comment: cross-posted to http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/47504/

Comment: I'm closing this question because it was cross-posted. Please don't cross-post.